# Efficient Canada investment account after maxing out TFSA that is not RRSP?

Tags: taxes, stocks, investing, canada

What kind of investment accounts in Canada are tax-efficient and allow holding U.S. stocks (Amazon, Google, etc.)?

I have maxed out my TFSA, and would prefer not to lock money in retirement-inclined and penalty-to-take-out accounts like RRSP.

Comment: Are you never intending to use RRSPs, or are you just wanting to wait until you are ready to invest for retirement?

Comment: I don't want to lock up money in a commitments such as RRSP for now, which penalizes upon withdrawal for other needs. I would like to manage money myself and that my money is available to flow for other purpose whenever I need it.

Comment: Remember, Investing in RRSP reduces the taxes you owe.

Comment: But yet even more penalized when I take them out ? https://www.ratehub.ca/investing/rrsp-withdrawal-rules Does it mean if I put 30k in it, gain 1500 and withdraw, I am taxed 30% on the entire 31500 (taxed applied even on the original 30k saving), leaving me appx. 31500*0.7=22050. Whereas for non-registered accounts, I am only taxed on 1500 capital gain, leaving me appx.  30k+1500- small tax on 1500 = 31k+ ? In which I even lose 9k by putting in RRSP !?

Comment: Say your annual income is 100k, if you put 10K in RRSP, you would be taxed as if you only earned 90K for that year.  The 10K + any gain is taxed when you take it out of the RRSP.  For TFSA, you pay tax on your whole 100K even if you put 10K in TFSA (within contribution rules/limits) and 0 taxes on any gains.  Typically you take money out of RRSP when you retire because most people would be earning far less at that point in life and would be taxed in a different bracket.

Comment: Personally what I do is 
1.  invest in RRSP
2.  Get a lump sum tax refund.  
3.  Invest the refund in TFSA
4.  Max out TFSA room.
5.  Go to Step 1.

Comment: Hi Viv, awesome answer. My follow up is in the comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Canada only TFSAs and RRSPs are tax efficient in the sense that they allow you to forgo paying taxes on dividends and capital gains (TFSAs), or defer paying taxes until a later time (RRSPs). Any major bank will be able to set up an investment account for you where you can buy/sell/trade US equities. You will have to pay capital gains taxes on any dividends that your equities generate, and when you sell your stocks you will have to pay capital gains taxes on any increase in the value of the stock. If you are holding US equities you will also need to pay foreign withholding taxes on any dividends that you earn. So in order to make your account the most tax efficient you should avoid investments which generate large dividend payments.

I would also say that an RRSP is frequently a better investment vehicle than a TFSA. [This website covers the basics](https://help.wealthsimple.com/hc/en-ca/articles/115015719107-Should-I-use-a-TFSA-or-an-RRSP-), but you should also consider the fact that you can take the tax refund that you get and invest that as well where it can also experience compounding interest. So don't rule out RRSPs just because you'll eventually have to pay some tax on them.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I don't rule out RRSPs because of tax, [on the contrary wouldn't it be for tax-advantage ?]. I don't want to lock my money in accounts which are only interesting at retirement and penalize you otherwise if you need it before that. Beside RRSP and TFSA, what are other kind of accounts that support US equity and interesting tax-wise ?

Comment: @Kenny (1) You can also make withdrawals from RRSPs with no penalty to buy a house, or to invest in your education. (2) With both an RRSP and a TFSA you are paying tax on the money-- for an RRSP you pay it when you withdraw the funds, for a TFSA you pay income tax on it before you even put it in the account. So don't think that you're somehow avoiding all taxes by using a TFSA (3) RRSP and TFSAs are the only types of accounts that offer you tax benefits for investing in them. Everything else will just be a non-registered investment account.

Comment: I don't look to avoid all taxes altogether since it's impossible. I am looking to limit the damage. https://www.ratehub.ca/investing/rrsp-withdrawal-rules Do I understand correctly that for RRSP, you're penalized even more upon withdrawal before retirement ? Meaning if I put 30k in it, gain 1500 and withdraw, I am taxed 30% on the entire 31500 (taxed applied even on the original 30k saving), leaving me appx. 31500*0.7=22050. Whereas for non-registered accounts, I am only taxed on 1500 capital gain, leaving me appx.  30k+1500-tax on 1500 = 31k+ ? In which I even lose 9k by putting in RRSP !?

Comment: @Kenny You have missed the fact that you got back the tax on the $30k investment when you put it in.

Comment: Right, what @DJClayworth said. Imagine you get the tax back on it. So for an RRSP you contribute 30K and you get 9K back as part of your tax refund at the end of the year (assuming a 30% marginal tax rate). Then you make 1.5K on your investment, and then withdraw everything. You're correct in that you'll have $22050 after taxes on your investment BUT you'll also have the initial 9K tax rebate-- which you could have invested and had it gaining interest too. You may want to do more research on the pros and cons of TFSA vs. RRSP.

Comment: Think of the RRSP rebate as an interest free loan from the government. You have to pay it back at some point, but you can use it to invest in the meantime.

Comment: Great answer, Viv, Dugan and DJ. I get to understand better the tax rebate when putting into RRSP. However, when looking at marginal tax rate https://turbotax.intuit.ca/tips/an-overview-of-federal-tax-rates-286 , most tax rate will be less than 30% (max 29% up to $210,371). So unless you make more than that (which is not for a typical person with a day job), the tax saved by putting into RRSP of my 30K is likely 20-26% (tax bracket up to $147,667), whereas when withdrawn, it is taxed flat rate at 30%. That means you save ~20% and lose a flat rate 30%, unless you wait to withdraw at retirement.

Comment: @Kenny No. the 30% tax is a withholding tax. It is not additive. It counts towards your paid income tax for that year. [Read this website](https://retirehappy.ca/understanding-withholding-tax-in/). You absolutely should not be using an RRSP if you plan on putting money in and withdrawing it in the same year. But for any kind of saving over the long-term an RRSP will always beat a TFSA because you are getting to defer your tax payments until later. This means that you have MORE MONEY during that time that you can INVEST which can gain more INTEREST.

Comment: Not to mention at withdrawal, that 30K+ adds back to the income of that year, making it **double tax** and you'll effectively lose 30% flat + additional income tax on that 30K at around 20% -> a whooping 50% gone ! So you save tax of 20% on 30K (6K) by putting into RRSP, invest rigorously with sweat and time to make 40K (that's already too optimistic; 33% return), then withdraw and are given back 20K. Add 6K saved to that, and it means you're with 26K on initial 30K .. That seems a lot of effort to lose money. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Kenny, I don't know how else to explain it. On both investments you are going to pay tax. For a TFSA you pay the income tax first at your marginal tax rate. The advantage of the RRSP is that you get that tax rebated to you initially which means that you can use it to invest and gain interest. If you're not investing the rebate and gaining interest you're correct in that they have the approximately the same returns. But why wouldn't you invest the rebate as well? This is akin to paying your taxes early because you don't feel like having extra money around.

Comment: TFSAs are great if you want to save up for something that you will be buying in the next few years (excluding houses or continuing education), or if you anticipate having to move money out of the account often. But for any long-term saving an RRSP is going to beat a TFSA because: (1) You get to reinvest your tax rebate and earn interest and (2) RRSPs are exempt from foreign withholding taxes that will be applied to dividends from your investments if you are buying US equities.

Comment: Thanks Dugan for the insights. From what you said, the withdrawn money is not double tax but only withheld 30% **once** to count towards my tax payment for that year ? That mean the real tax rate on that withdrawn 40K is not 30% but may be 26% or 33% depending on my income. My situation is I want to grow money, and perhaps a few years may move to another country, take that out to use there. I don't intend to leave it til retirement. I was concerned of locked money and too much penalty at withdrawal.

Comment: Speaking from experience, locked money is considered out of hand. I have worked in a couple of countries like France, Singapore, forced contribute huge amount to the retirement and perhaps will never see them again. That's why I would prefer to have money at my hand to use as will. Your input make me think of an option: put it in RRSP, when I move, one year later (no longer with Canadian income), withdraw and that counts towards income but with lower tax bracket, similar to retirement. How does it sound ? Also, could you elaborate 2nd point about 'exempt from foreign withholding taxes'

Comment: @Kenny Correct. The 30% tax that is withheld counts towards your income tax for that year which will be at your marginal rate. But a two-year timeline almost negates the benefits of having the extra tax rebate to invest (it's hard to get a great return over only 2 years), and it is admittedly more time consuming to withdraw money from an RRSP compared to a TFSA -- not something you necessarily want to be doing when moving. I would say that if you were dealing with a 5 year time scale or longer an RRSP might make more sense. I'm not sure how holding a RRSP in a foreign country would work either

Comment: Foreign withholding taxes are taxes that are applied when you are receiving income from foreign countries. e.g. If you buy US equities and they pay you a dividend on your shares those dividends will be taxed at a rate of 15%. [See this website for more details](https://www.moneysense.ca/columns/foreign-withholding-tax-explained/). If you hold the funds in an RRSP these fees are waived. If you have them in a TFSA they will be automatically deducted from your dividend payments (after you complete a little bit of paperwork-- if you don't complete the paperwork they'll be taxed at a rate of 35%)

Comment: You can get around this issue by only holding Canadian equities, or holding Canadian equities that track US markets. e.g. VUN is a Canadian ETF which tracks the US total stock market. The issue with this is that they just bake the foreign withholding fees right into the MER of the fund. So you'll have a smaller return.

Comment: I did have Canadian ETFs that track US equities in my TFSA portfolio that is already filled. They are not as performant as certain US equities. With your advice, I think RRSP may be another option after TFSA. The overseas move is in the time frame of upcoming 4-6 years, which, as you said, may not generate much difference. But the tax defer and waived foreign dividend may be interesting. When I move, wait for the following year when there is no income to withdraw, would that have the same effect as retirement withdrawal, in which the amount at that time contributes to the lowest tax bracket ?

Comment: Whatever your income for that year is (including withdraws from your RRSP) would determine your marginal tax rate. If it was lower at the time of withdrawal than it was when you contributed then you would have an added tax savings.

Comment: Interesting. Can you see if the following analysis is correct : I contribute to RRSP while working from now. End 2024, quit job in CA and leave to US. Somewhere in 2025,withdraw the RRSP, let's say 40K, withholding tax is 30% which is 12K. April 2026, tax is calculated on total 2025 income, which is that withdrawn amount, and falls into the bracket of 25%, resulting in 10K. Will I be reimbursed 2K overcharged, since I will not have any other tax to pay in Canada ? If not, how is that 2K dealt with ?

Comment: @Kenny. Actually your tax rate on 40K would only be 20% [(assuming your only income is the 40K)](https://neuvoo.ca/tax-calculator/Ontario-40000). You should be reimbursed any overcharges in the same manner that you receive your regular tax return. However, this is a unique situation I've never encountered so I would discuss with your tax accountant or call CRA to confirm that this is what would happen before proceeding with this plan.

Comment: And here I thought many would fall into this category.Not everyone stay in one place until retirement nowadays;or even retire at the age of retirement. It has not been like in the past when one got a job, start a family, buy a house and work the same job until retirement. And yet systems still impose that on people. Not to mention every country keeps pushing retirement age, at some places 70+ now. Exactly for that,I won't want my money to be forced locked by someone else and lost.E.g.:my forced contribution in France is lost since I would need to work 45-50 years (and increasing) to touch that